# Help finding some specific function $f(x)$

Tags: functions, inequality, summation

I am trying to optimize an inequality to solve a problem, and I need to find some function $f(x)$ such that $$\sum_{k=1}^{\sqrt{x}} \frac{f\left(\frac{x}{k}\right)}{\sqrt{k}} \geq \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\log(x)} + \frac{2\sqrt{x}}{\log^2(x)}$$ The inequality needs to be as tight as possible.

Through empirical experimentation and a Python program, I guess that the best $f(x)$ could be $f(x)=\log\log(x)^\theta$, where $\theta$ is some function that grows slightly faster than $\sqrt{\log\log(x)}$.

However, I don't know how to prove it, and as $f(x)$ has been obtained through experimentation, I would like to know

(i) if the conjectured best $f(x)$ can be proved to be such.

(ii) if there is some other function that could make the inequality to be more tight.

(iii) if there are other functions that maybe are not the best, but are "good enough" and such that they can be proved to satisfy the inequality.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

I have tried some approaches, and I think I have found a good bound for $f(x)$.

It can be showed that $$\sum_{k=1}^{\sqrt{x}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}<2\sqrt[4]{x}+1$$

Other hand, if we assume that $f(x)$ is some continuous and increasing function, we have that $$f(\sqrt{x})<f\left(\frac{x}{k}\right)<f(x)$$ for $1\leq k\leq \sqrt{x}$

Applying both results, we have that $$2\sqrt[4]{x}\cdot f(\sqrt{x})<\sum_{k=1}^{\sqrt{x}} \frac{f\left(\frac{x}{k}\right)}{\sqrt{k}}<2\sqrt[4]{x}\cdot f(x)$$

Therefore, dividing both sides of the inequality we want to hold by $2\sqrt[4]{x}$, we have that $$f(g(x))\geq \frac{\sqrt[4]{x}}{2\log(x)} + \frac{\sqrt[4]{x}}{\log^2(x)}$$

$$f(g(x))\geq \sqrt[4]{x} \cdot \left(\frac{1}{2\log(x)} + \frac{1}{\log^2(x)}\right)$$

$$f(g(x))\geq \frac{\sqrt[4]{x}}{\log(x)} \cdot \left(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{\log(x)}\right)$$

Therefore, for $x>e^2$, we have that $$\frac{\sqrt[4]{x}}{2\log(x)}\leq f(g(x))< \frac{\sqrt[4]{x}}{\log(x)}$$

Where $\sqrt{x}<g(x)<x$.

As a result, we can set $f(x)=\frac{\sqrt[4]{x}}{\log(x)}$ as a function that guarantees the inequality $\sum_{k=1}^{\sqrt{x}} \frac{f\left(\frac{x}{k}\right)}{\sqrt{k}} \geq \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\log(x)} + \frac{2\sqrt{x}}{\log^2(x)}$ to be tight.

Do you think that $f(x)$ can be improved further?